# Renewing EU Blue Card in France after resigning

Tags: resident-permit, france, eu, blue-card, unemployment-benefits

I have an EU Blue Card issued by France since 2019 which expires in April 2023. I was working until December 2021 and then in 2022, I was enrolled in a Masters program in France. I studied while on a 'training leave' (conge formation) from work. So, I was studying on my EU Blue Card and did not have a student visa. Now, I wish to quit my job and search for something better. However, the issue I face is that for my renewal, I need an employer attestation, which I will not have if I quit.

I am not sure about the options that I have. These are the questions that are stuck in my head while I try to make a decision.

- Should I stay with my employer till I receive the récépissé ?
- Can I quit and still apply for a renewal of the Blue Card?
- Can I quit and apply for a job search visa?
- Do I qualify for pole emploi (unemployment benefits)? If so, can I prolong my stay using this?

I'm looking for any guidance from the community as I am genuinely lost.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I stay with my employer till I receive the récépissé?

This sounds like the safest plan. Generally speaking, I don't see many benefits in quitting before you found another job. Do no underestimate how long recruitment processes can be in France.

Even after renewing the card, you would be on a clock to find a new job and at the mercy of the *préfecture*.  If you can help it and can tolerate your current job, I strongly recommend against creating that kind of pressure for yourself.

> Can I quit and still apply for a renewal of the Blue Card?

No, a form from your employer and various other documens related to your job / occupation are indeed explicit requirements. You would risk a refusal and OQTF (giving you 30 days to leave France) and would be even worse off.

> Can I quit and apply for a job search visa?

I don't know about that. The visa seems designed for people who came to France as students and [service-public](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F17319) lists a student residence permit as one of the requirements. You won't be able to present that, which makes this route risky.

> Do I qualify for pole emploi (unemployment benefits)? If so, can I prolong my stay using this?

Not if your quit without justification. You can only get unemployment benefits if you are laid off, fired (even fired for cause, unless it's a *faute lourde*), or quit for a number of specific reasons (like moving to live with your spouse after the wedding). I am not sure how the time spent studying under the *congé formation* would count towards your unemployment benefits but this is moot if you quit.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is incredibly helpful!